# Any way I could optimize this SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

So my query does work, but it takes about 25-30 seconds to complete. I was wanting to know if theres anything I could do with this query to optimize it so it may run a bit faster? Ive done some myself, but it still runs arround 25 seconds at best.

Any advice or help? Even just a point in the right direction would be more than appreciated.

```
    SELECT * FROM `earnfrom` WHERE (
            `active` = ? AND `type` = ?
    )
    AND `curdaily` <= `dailyclick` AND `clicks` <= `totalclick` AND `id` NOT IN (
        SELECT `earnid` FROM `earnedby` WHERE `userid`= ?
    )
    AND `userid` != ? AND  (
        SELECT `points` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = `userid`
    ) >= `cpc` ORDER BY `cpc` DESC, RAND()")
```

Here's the table schemes:

TABLE earnedby:
[earnedby](http://prntscr.com/2xpmmn)

TABLE earnfrom:
[earnfrom](http://prntscr.com/2xpmon)

TABLE users:
prntscr.com/2xpmre

DB has 2711 links with the same type (Facebook Likes) and it needs to get those who hasn't been liked (NOT IN (SELECT * FROM `....) but that NOT IN is making a pain since a week (since I am getting more than 210 users daily)

So the query should be doing this:

SELECT a link from the db, verify if daily limit click is being equal, select those who arent equal, verify if the `id` exist in another table (earnedby) as earnid, if not that one should be good, if it exists it means its actually already liked, or there was a problem when likin

Thank-you for considering my question~

Comment: No query plan -> no help.

Comment: Added a better description~

Comment: Who cares about the description, *what is the query plan*?

Comment: What is it you mean by 'the query plan'?

Comment: Updated, is that what you meant?

Comment: Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html - while somewhat crude, MySQL's explain should indicate which indices are being used. A query is generally slow when it is *not* sargable or the query planner fails to correctly use indices. (I won't even pretend to guess what MySQL is choosing what plans it does these days ..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the subqueries from WHERE section into FROM section with appropriate join.

E.g. like this

```
SELECT * FROM `earnfrom` 
    join `users` on `users`.`id` = `earnfrom`.`userid` 
    left join (select `earnid` from FROM `earnedby` WHERE `userid`= ?) sub ON sub.`earnid`=`earnfrom`.`userid`
WHERE (
        `active` = ? AND `type` = ?
)
AND `curdaily` <= `dailyclick` 
AND `clicks` <= `totalclick` 
AND sub.`earnid` is NULL
AND `userid` != ? AND  `users`.`points` >= `cpc` 
ORDER BY `cpc` DESC, RAND()")
```

Comment: Thankyou this worked beautifully, I wish I could give you a hug sir :)

Comment: Done, thankyou, using yours + changing != to <> my query now runs in well under 1 second. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an MySQL expert, so i use Percona Query Adviser to analyze my query before implement. Its a good place to start.

```
https://tools.percona.com/query-advisor/
```